# How to replace the a iframe into another if type="text/html"?

Tags: javascript, iframe, replace

I have this:

```
<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
src="http://widget.smartycenter.com/webservice/directYoutube/8982/YOUTUBE_CODE/640/360" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And if the iframe's type is **type="text/html"** I will replace it into

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_CODE" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I understand it this way: you're asking how to make the url change if the iframe has that type.

Comment: yes, that's it. I just wanna change the url

Comment: I want to have the original url from youtube.com

Comment: Is `8982` a permanent part of the URL or is it unique for every YOUTUBE_CODE?

Comment: Select the target `iframe` tags using `document.querySelectorAll('iframe[type="text/html"]')` and then setAttribute/removeAttribute accordingly

Comment: it's permanent, but that doesn't mind, because I wanna remove the entire src and put the original youtube link, the only important there is the youtube video code

Comment: I know; I'm using regexes so that detail was important. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for any iframe of that type.

```
var frames = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[type="text/html"]');
for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    var oldFrame = frames[i];

    var re = /http:\/\/widget\.smartycenter\.com\/webservice\/directYoutube\/\d{4}\/([^\/]+)\/640\/360/;
    var code = re.exec(oldFrame.src)[1];
    var src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + code;

    var newFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
    newFrame.width = 560; newFrame.height = 315;
    newFrame.allowfullscreen = true;
    newFrame.frameborder = 0;
    newFrame.src = src;

    oldFrame.parentElement.replaceChild(newFrame, oldFrame);
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9a9t3/

Make sure to change YOUTUBE_CODE in the HTML section to the code you want.

Comment: @user204415 I don't understand Spanish. Could you please say what doesn't work in English?

Comment: well, I have tried to run your code using tampermonkey and it doesn't change the src.

Comment: @user204415 My bad. I fixed it now, try again. It was only a syntax error after all.

Comment: no, It's not working, you can test it, just use tampermonkey or tamperdata

Comment: @user204415 It works. Check out the attached jsFiddle link (and change "YOUTUBE_CODE" to the YT code you want in the HTML box.

Comment: yes, it's working fine in jsFiddle, so why is not working on that site? it's strange.

Comment: could you please try to use tampermonkey ?

Comment: @user204415 I don't really know about tampermonkey. Since your original question does not ask about tampermonkey specifically, this answer is correct. If this didn't help then accept this answer and start a new question asking specifically about tampermonkey.